# How to make a get request from html to server

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create a button the user can click to see all users in the database. (Just for testing)
in my html page I have:

```
  <form action="/server.js" method="get">
          <button type="submit" name="users">users</button>
        </form>
```

and in server.js I have:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res) => {
  Users.find().then(users => res.json(users));
});
```

When I click the button I see :
Cannot GET /server.js

Can anybody see what the correct syntax for this GET request is?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> app.get('/users'
> ```

You've defined a route for the URL `/users`

So that is the URL you have to ask for.

```
action="/users"
```

Answer (score 1):

your action should be `action="/users"` since the server is responding to this route with a get request as you wrote in your server.js file